# How do I directly show that Log is discontinuous on the interval $\{-\infty<\Re z\le 0\}?$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, logarithms

Given the knowledge that the exponential function maps bijectively each half-open horizontal strip of width $2\pi$ onto $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}.$  So, in particular, if we restrict it to $-\pi<\Im z\le \pi$ , we get the principal logarithm Log$:C\setminus \{0\}\to  -\pi<\Im z\le \pi$. Then this function is analytic $except$ on the interval $\{-\infty<\Re z\le 0\}.$

I'm trying to see what happens as I approach any given point in the interval $\{-\infty<\Re z\le 0\}$ not equal to zero from $\Im z > 0$ and $\Im z < 0$. But I can't see exactly why it's discontinuous on the interval $\{-\infty<\Re z\le 0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x$ on the negative real axis write down $log (x+\frac i n)$ and $Log(x-\frac i n)$. It is quite easy to see that these sequences tend to different limits.

Comment: Graphically, I'm able to see that the limit for $\operatorname{Log}(x + \frac{i}{n})$ lies above $\Im z = 0$ and the limit for $\operatorname{Log}(x- \frac{i}{n})$ lies below $\Im z = 0$, but how would I go about proving it?

Comment: The imaginary part of the first sequence tends to $\pi$ and the imaginary part of the second tends to $-\pi$. Remember that the imaginary part of $Log(z)$ belongs to $(-\pi,\pi)$.